# Passing String variable from Java to JavaScript via Webview (vice versa)

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am trying to make an app where two users can interact through webview. I want to get a String variable from javascript to Java so that I can save it in my Sqlite database.(And vice versa)

Comment: `implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'`

Comment: May be you can go through this https://medium.com/@sreeharikv112/communication-from-webview-to-native-ios-android-app-6d842cefe02d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Calling Java/Kotlin code from JavaScript**

There's a feature of Android WebView called [Javascript Interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript) which is what you should look for.

It allows you to run your java/kotlin code from your javascript code.

You can define an interface by

```
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Android")
```

Here, **WebAppInterface** defines the methods which you want to be called from javascript.

```
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context  */
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {
     /** Show a toast from the web page  */
     @JavascriptInterface
     fun showToast(toast: String) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     }
}
```

"**Android**" here is an interface added to your webview and can be used in your javascript code to call Android methods.

Once this is done, you can call the methods from your javascript,

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
}
</script>
```

Keep in mind that the interface callbacks are not always called in main thread. So, if you want to perform any UI operations, make sure you use **runOnUiThread**.

**Calling JavaScript function from Java/Kotlin code**

There's a feature of Android WebView called [Evaluate Javascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) for API 19+ to call your javascript functions from java/kotlin code.

For example, for the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printName(name) {
    console.log(name); 
}
</script>
```

You can write this code to call this JS function:

```
yourWebview.evaluateJavascript("printName(\'TEST\')")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer seems to show how to execute a Java function from Javascript. And What can I do if I want to execute a Javascript function from Java? @Maulik Hirani

Comment: @MbulaMbomaJeangilbert, updated the answer with the solution to call JS function from Java/Kotlin code :)